# wordpress permalink not working when double dot in url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

permalinks is not working in wordpress after migration from one server to other.i tried everything in wordpress permalinks settings and in .htaccess file but it's not worked. Actually my new url like

test.testserver.abc.com

i set custom structure (/%postname%/) from permalink settings.

here is auto generated .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: After migrating from one server to another server , you should login to admin end an click permalink and click save button again and check all links will work as expected.

Comment: "Not working" is not a **clear problem statement**.  _Define the problem_: What happens? What doesn't happen?  This sounds much more like a server config issue than a WP or htaccess issue, but it's hard to know without more information.

Comment: Sorry for little info, thanx for correction. actually when i set permalinks settings to custom structure then it can't working and shows  'The requested URL was not found on this server'

Comment: @ManoharSingh i tried this many time but it still not working.

Comment: Ok then there might be some problem during migration , use this plugin to migrate the DB again https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/